# Sqlserver minus with unmatched columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with different columns and want `intersect` records.

**Table1:**

```
Id       name       age
1        AAA        20
2        AAA        30
3        BBB        25
4        BBB        30
```

**Table2:**

```
         name      age
         AAA       20
         BBB       30
```

**Expect Output:(Table2 - Table1)**

```
Id     name     age
2      AAA      30
3      BBB      25
```

Comment: "want" isn't a question. Someone with almost 10K reputation *should* know how to ask a question when posting one and how to show their efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery to check that no tuple `(name, age)` with identical values exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM table2 t2
                                WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                                      AND t2.age = t1.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Right Join`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table1.Age
FROM Table2  RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name AND Table1.Age = Table2.Age
WHERE Table2.Name IS NULL
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86670cf4756fc765946a43a4e0e8ee13)**

Comment: @Srinivasan You can use `Right` join